# databricks AttributeError:'function" object has no attribute eval_fn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, databricks

When the run the code below in databricks, which is from here:https://www.databricks.com/blog/2022/04/19/model-evaluation-in-mlflow.html, I get the error:  AttributeError:'function" object has no attribute eval_fn.  Any ideas on what I can do? Thank you!

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mlflow
import os

# loading the California housing dataset
cali_housing = fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True)

# split the dataset into train and test partitions
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
   cali_housing.data, cali_housing.target, test_size=0.2, random_state=123
)

# train the model
lin_reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

# creating the evaluation dataframe
eval_data = X_test.copy()
eval_data["target"] = y_test
def example_custom_metric_fn(eval_df, builtin_metrics, artifacts_dir):
   """
   This example custom metric function creates a metric based on the ``prediction`` and
   ``target`` columns in ``eval_df`` and a metric derived from existing metrics in
   ``builtin_metrics``. It also generates and saves a scatter plot to ``artifacts_dir`` that
   visualizes the relationship between the predictions and targets for the given model to a
   file as an image artifact.
   """
   metrics = {
       "squared_diff_plus_one": np.sum(np.abs(eval_df["prediction"] - eval_df["target"] + 1) ** 2),
       "sum_on_label_divided_by_two": builtin_metrics["sum_on_label"] / 2,
   }
   plt.scatter(eval_df["prediction"], eval_df["target"])
   plt.xlabel("Targets")
   plt.ylabel("Predictions")
   plt.title("Targets vs. Predictions")
   plot_path = os.path.join(artifacts_dir, "example_scatter_plot.png")
   plt.savefig(plot_path)
   artifacts = {"example_scatter_plot_artifact": plot_path}
   return metrics, artifacts

with mlflow.start_run() as run:
   mlflow.sklearn.log_model(lin_reg, "model")
   model_uri = mlflow.get_artifact_uri("model")
   result = mlflow.evaluate(
       model=model_uri,
       data=eval_data,
       targets="target",
       model_type="regressor",
       dataset_name="cali_housing",
       custom_metrics=[example_custom_metric_fn],
   )
```